# PowerShell: how is the index out of bounds?

Tags: powershell

I want to know how the index for `$ServiceName` is out of bounds.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$ServiceName
)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ServiceName.Count; $i++) {
    $srv[$i] = gwmi win32_service -Filter "Name='$($ServiceName[$i])'"
}
```

Also, do I need to initialize `$srv`? Ex. `$srv = @()`

NEVERMIND, I FOUND THE SOLUTION:

```
$srv[$i] = gwmi win32_service **-ComputerName $ComputerName** -Filter "Name='$($ServiceName[$i])'"
```

I forgot to add the computername.

Comment: See `$f = @("a", "b", "c"); $f.count; $f[2], $f[$f.count]`

Comment: If you found the solution, post an answer!